# Store image as value in Android Studio

Tags: android, button

This is a code when user choose one image and will run this coding (finish()), if choose wrong image then do not run the finish() .
        but i dont know how to make the image as a value  , how i select the drawable a or b or c and link to this function

```
  if(eyeDected)
                    {
                        if(detectedFrame > 25)
                        {
                            eyeDected = false;
                            detectedFrame = 0;
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            detectedFrame++;
                            Log.d("UNLOCK:", String.valueOf(detectedFrame));
                        }
                    } else {
                        eyeDected = true;
                        detectedFrame++;
                        Log.d("UNLOCK:", String.valueOf(detectedFrame));
                    }
```

I want to ask about how to store the drawble/image into value?
i'm developing a lock screen application , when user choose the correct image will execute the unlock function
This is a layout showing 3 images and give user choose one images inside a lock screen.

In the setting , i'll let user to choose one image as the correct image that will execute the code

set_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/new_build_resize_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/setting">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Image "
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="38dp"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_light" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select one graphical passcode as your lock screen."
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#1547bb"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:src="@drawable/c"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use tag or custom attribute for `ImageView`

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand, buy why store the whole image and not store a value associated with the image on an onClick event? image_a, image_b or whatever the name is.


If you really really really want it, I guess you could get the Bitmap
`((BitmapDrawable) imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`
and base64 it.

Comment: eyeDected from mainactivity.java but for now i havent the image.java which is link to the set_image.xml